# Cannot iterate through array in Slim's logic

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I am trying to iterate through an array named `@items`. I thought by adding it to a class variable and calling it from SLIM I might be able to output the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "slim"
set :port, 80
get "/" do
  slim :index
end
get "/history" do
  @items = Dir.entries(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "/history").to_a
  slim :history
end
__END__
@@layout
doctype html
html
  head
    title Web View
  body
    div id="main" name="main"
      h1 Web View
      == yield
@@index
h2 Available Options
a href="/history" id="history_view" name="history_view" History
@@history
h2 History
- unless items.empty?
  - for item in items do
    a href="#{item}/output.html" item
  - else
    p NO ITEMS FOUND
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've tried to call `items` method in your 'history' layout. Besides this look at indentation level for your `else` clause. Try to change your code:

```
h2 History
- unless @items.empty?
  - for item in @items do
    a href="#{item}/output.html" item
- else
    p NO ITEMS FOUND
```

Comment: Not at all, glad to help you :)